# cron kohana 3.3 wrong parametr in cli

Tags: php, cron, kohana

I am getting this error

> Parameter Errors:
>       uri - uri is not a valid option for this task!

but my command looks valid:

> php /var/www/public_html/index.php --uri=controller/action

i tried also (direct in this folder)

> php index.php --uri=controller/action
>
> php index.php --uri="controller/action"

always this error

greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kohana 3.3 changed the way it handles CLI execution. From 3.3 it uses Minion module and `--uri` param is dropped in favour of `--task`, therefore you have to create Tasks (as opposed to Controllers).

More in the docs: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/minion/tasks

Note that docs have an error, there's no `$_defaults` any more, there's `$_options` instead. Have a look into [API Docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Minion_Task) for more details.